# не работает простой код: NameError: name 'math' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
>>> def square(n):
    S = n**2
    P = n*4
    d = math.sqrt((n**2)*2)
    c = tuple(S, P, d)
    c


>>> square(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 1, in <module>
square(10)
  File "<pyshell#62>", line 4, in square
d = math.sqrt((n**2)*2)
NameError: name 'math' is not defined
```

Я вроде бы всё делаю по инструкциям из самоучителя https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python. Но всё равно ошибки выдаёт почему?

Comment: Покажите в какой именно инструкции был тот код :)

Comment: Если у вас появился новый вопрос, используйте кнопку [«Задать вопрос»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Нельзя стирать старый текст вопроса и писать новый вместо старого.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка потому-то в коде нет сущности `math`, а т.к. это модуль, его нужно импортировать

Добавляйте перед выполнением кода строку:

```
import math
```

Это модуль [math](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html) и у него есть метод [sqrt](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/math.html#math.sqrt)

Comment: Поясните, для чего ее добавлять?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не сделали импорт модуля math.

В начале кода пропишите `import math`

В коде вы используете функцию `math.sqrt()`, но скрипту не от куда знать что это такое, пока не прописать импорт.